# While Loop waiting for global variable not triggering

Tags: c, arm, embedded, atmelstudio

I have a flag (as a global variable) which is waiting for a certain time to pass before being set.  I have a while loop which waits for the flag to set before proceeding.  The global variable does get set to '1' but the while loop does not exit, any ideas what I'm doing wrong:

```
while (TC3Flag == 0); //Global Flag Variabe TC3Flag, 0 = Not Set, 1 = Set
TurnOnFive();
TurnOnTwelve();
TC3Flag = 0;
```

Edit i also have tried with the same results, I do want the processor to do nothing while the flag is 0 and only call TurnOnFive and TurnOnTwleve after the flag is set

```
    while (TC3Flag == 0) {}
    TurnOnFive();
    TurnOnTwelve();
    TC3Flag = 0;
```

EDIT EDIT: Adding volitile to the TC3FLag declaration fixed it.

Comment: There's a spurious semicolon after the condition so that the loop has no body. Remove it.

Comment: @MOehm I think that's the intention

Comment: Is your TC3Flag variable marked `volatile` ? As that variable seems to be able to change outside of the regular program flow, it should be.

Comment: BTW Who is changing `TC3Flag`?

Comment: Adding Volitile ended up fixing it thanks!

Comment: I am interested in knowing how is `TC3Flag` getting changed?

Comment: Try to give Correct code snippet to avoid confusions.

Comment: @zappy What's wrong with the code snippet?

Comment: @MOehm The while loop is a busy wait. The semicolon should be there.

Comment: @klutt: Yes, I've unserstood that by now. Thanks for pointing it out again.

Comment: Nothing guarantees atomic access either... unless you use the atomic types :D

Answer (score 12):

Unless `TC3Flag` is marked as `volatile`, the compiler can aggressively optimize the loop away *(or just assume it's an infinite loop)*. You should mark `TC3Flag` as `volatile` in order to force the compiler to read the value at its memory address on every iteration.